# Implementing realtime search results in Android

Tags: android, http, search, provider

How does one go about implementing realtime search suggestions in the way Google Finance android app does?

Let's say I can retrieve xml responses from xyz.com/quote/tickers=aapl,goog,....

Thus far, I have implemented intents and actions which take the user's complete query string and load a fragment. What I am looking for is a solution where the user can get results from xyz.com as he enters each character. That means we need to hit the quote url for characters as they are entered and display the xml response in the dropdown.

#### Desired behavior:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Sounds like you already know what to do :)

Comment: Not really. I know what needs to be done. No idea how to go about it from an implementation standpoint. The best examples are StockChaos and Google Finance apps in the android marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

If that xyz.com have Database hit that DB with query using LIKE operator(%) it ll give matched results.for displaying xml response we can use jersey API. http://jersey.java.net/, for each character use Key down Event.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime search suggestion(or auto completion) is better implemented using a data structure called [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), with a Trie, you load all the candidate keywords in memory, and search against the Trie in memory, that would be much faster than fetching the search result from another service over HTTP, and I doubt if it could be *realtime* if you have to do the search over HTTP.

Sure there're limitations by using Trie if the keyword dataset to be loaded is large, you might not be able to use it in an Android application.

Well there's also a compressed trie called [Patricia Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), which consumes less memory than traditional trie.

Answer (score 0):

[The Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) describe how to create a `ContenProvider` for your search suggestions.